# Google Maps API Navigation Event Listener (turn Left etc.)

Tags: android, events, navigation, maps, listener

i want to extract the events of a turn-by-turn navigation in google maps in my own app.

How do i expose the Google Maps API functionalities that i am able to get an event listener for example the events turn left or right.

I'm fine to embed GMaps in my app or just listend to any event when Gmaps is routing normally and my app is in the background.

I googled but didn't find anything useful...

Bye & thanks

Comment: This answer is a duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717457/get-google-maps-navigation-instructions