# Get Google Maps Navigation Instructions

Tags: android, google-maps, notifications, navigation, android-notifications

I'm looking for a way to get the instructions from Maps Navigation.
Currently I think the only possible way is to read the notification data that is placed at the top by Maps Navigation. My reason for beleving that this is the only way comes from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771812/how-to-launch-google-maps-navigation-and-get-feedback-in-app).
I tried getting the data with the OnNotificationPosted method, but i cant find directions data in the StatusBarNotification object...

Does anyone have a solution or better idea on how to achieve this

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/get-driving-directions-using-google-maps-api-v2/15053901#15053901. Also, here's a demo app: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

Comment: Unfortunately thats not what i'm looking for. I can get the directions object etc. from google, but i'm looking for a way to get realtime turn by turn directions based on geolocation.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing for few days as well. But I don't think those information are accessible.

Comment: I noticed that it is possible to read the notification that is placed in the top of the screen. But google maps change it from text like "Go Left", to an icon that displays the turn and I cant get the icon src. Hoped the icon source is something like "sharp_left_notificationicon.png" but cant get its value. I am a android beginner, so maybe you have more luck with getting the value, if so please let me know. If I have anything new ill post it here

Comment: I am facing same problem, did you find a solution? @ArthurVanSchravendijk

Comment: @Dany19 sorry for the extreem late response, never found a solution. was a project for graduation. So i let it go and faked it since it was only for a prototype. Hope you had better luck!

Comment: I've done a sample application and free library using the NotificationListenerService, you can get it at https://github.com/3v1n0/GMapsParser

Answer (score -1):

You can implement a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) in order to retrieve the content of google maps route direction. Unfortunately Maps is not using the common attributes within the StatusBarNotification. However maps uses `RemoteViews` to display content.
You can send this data via Broadcast to the activity and eventually add the content to an existing view:

```
RemoteViews remoteView = intent.getParcelableExtra(id);
if (remoteView != null) {
    ViewGroup frame = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_navi);
    frame.removeAllViews();
    View newView = remoteView.apply(getApplicationContext(), frame);
    newView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    frame.addView(newView);
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the solution! I have one question about it, With your solution I could create a frame to display the solution in an other place right? Or can I also see if google maps says left or right? Because I would like to use those instructions in code.

Comment: No, you can also traverse through the `newView` ViewGroup and get the contents of its children: `View viewImage = ((ViewGroup) newView).getChildAt(0);` and the text is inside: `View outerLayout = ((ViewGroup) newView).getChildAt(1);` and then traverse through the `outerLayout` to get the text content.

Comment: @droiddude can you explain your solution in more detail... How exactly does this solution show the directions or instructions that google maps notifications show